# Fill empty div with background and expand dimensions of parent a tag

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation which holds either text or images for links. I want the image to change on hover, so am using CSS backgrounds inside an empty div. However, I am looking for a way of doing this without using "position: absolute;" as the containing a tag will not expand to fill its dimensions. I would also like to do this without using a transparent placeholder image as I want to find a more elegant solution.

Here's the jsfiddle and the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/urhLs736/1/

```
<nav id="navigation">

    <ul>
        <li><a onclick="example1.html">PAGE 1</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="example2.html">PAGE 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="example3.html"><div id="nav-image"></div></a></li>

    </ul>

</nav>
```

and for the CSS:

```
    #navigation {
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #3A5E90;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #navigation.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
    }

    #navigation li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #navigation a {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-left: 3.5%;
        padding-right: 3.5%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navigation a:hover {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        color: #3A5E90;
        padding-top: 2%;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
    }

    #nav-image {
        display: inline;
        background: url('https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/3081095?v=2&s=72') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -6px;
        height: 24px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    #nav-image:hover {
        height: 24px;
        width: 100px;
        background: url('https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/5278945?v=2&s=96') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your layout will work as is with a minor adjustment to the CSS:

```
#nav-image {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/3081095?v=2&s=72') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
```

If you use `display: inline-block`, the `div` will take up the specified width and height and the background image will be visible, and the hover effect will work as you expect.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9fd1dxn4/

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you have to change both your HTML and your CSS.

First, your HTML should go like this:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a onclick="example1.html">PAGE 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a onclick="example2.html">PAGE 2</a>
        </li>
        <li id="nav-image"><a href="example3.html">PAGE 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Note that I have added some content in your empty div. If you have an empty `<li>`, you'll have no background at all (just like your example) since you have a 0x0 pixels `li` element. I have added some content so the `li` displays as a general rule, which anyways won't be necessary after you see the CSS, which is the following:

```
    #navigation {
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #3A5E90;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #navigation.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #navigation li {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 24px;
        width: 100px;
        padding-left: 3.5%;
        padding-right: 3.5%;
    }
    #navigation ul li a {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding:2% 3.5%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        display:block;
        height: 24px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    #navigation a:hover {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        color: #3A5E90;
    }
    #nav-image {
        background: url('https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/3081095?v=2&s=72') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
    #nav-image:hover {
        background: url('https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/5278945?v=2&s=96') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
    #nav-image:hover a {
        background:transparent
    }
```

OK, now you see I have made some changes and added width and height to the li (the same you had in your sample, but you can change it to anything you want). Now, if you delete the content inside the empty DIV, you'll see how the rendering changes. While it's very easy to solve, I'll leave it to you so you can practice and understand how the whole positioning and display thing works. Also, you can add paddings, margins, et

Here you have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6uw9947/) so you can see it in action and play around

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help :) Unfortunately this isn't quite what I'm looking for.. I don't want to specify the width and height in the a tag - I'm looking for a way for this tag to expand normally as if the div was a square. Mainly because I want cleaner code and will eventually scale this idea up on many images

Comment: In fact your question isn't very clear, that's why I left some things open for you to experiment, but you can totally remove the width and height (in that case you will need to add an element to the empty div, at least using the content property). As I said, I used that width and that height because you had it, you can use ANYTHING, which includes 1000px, 100% or... 0